# Make reading from PDAs private

Tags: pda, account, associated-token-account, seed

If I remember correctly, PDA can be found out by anyone who knows the seed, Public Keys and the Program ID related to a Solana program. Is there a mechanism through which no one except the public key holder (who the account belongs to) has any sort of access to the PDA account? No reading especially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly stated, anyone who knows the seeds can find the address of a PDA.

There is no mechanism to have a private PDA.

You can obfuscate the data instead, e.g. via encryption or some other mechanism, so that only the holder of the public key can make sense of the data

Answer (score 0):

everything that goes on chain is Public irrespective of who the owner is So in order to make it private you have to implement some sort of encryption and decryption